# I am trying to follow the documentation, but my modal is not showing up when I press what I have surrounded with Pressable

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, modal-dialog

I was going to use Touchable opacity as a wrapper but the docs directed me to pressable, and I can see the component being pressed, but the modal is not showing up. Does it have something to do with my CSS or did I mess up the modal implementation. Also, I am trying to have options in the modal that then are used to alter the state of the original page to display items. Does anyone have any documentation for me to read on how to pass information from page to page?

Here is my code:

```
import {LeftTextRightIcon} from '@atoms/LeftTextRightIcon';
import {Text, TextTypes} from '@atoms/Text';
import styled from '@styled-components';
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {Modal, Pressable} from 'react-native';

export interface ISortFilterCategory {
  title: string;
}

export const SortFilterCategory: React.FC<ISortFilterCategory> = ({
  title,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Container {...props}>
      <TopContainer>
        <TitleContainer>
          <TitleText>{title}</TitleText>
        </TitleContainer>
        <ButtonContainers>
          <FirstModal
            visible={modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
              setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            }}>
            <ModalContent>
              <TitleContainer>
                <TitleText>{title}</TitleText>
              </TitleContainer>
            </ModalContent>
          </FirstModal>
          <Pressable onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
            <LeftTextRightIcon text="Sort" icon="chevron-down" />
          </Pressable>
          <LeftTextRightIcon text="Filter" icon="chevron-down" />
          <LeftTextRightIcon text="Category" icon="chevron-down" />
        </ButtonContainers>
      </TopContainer>
      <BottomContainer />
    </Container>
  );
};
const Container = styled.View`
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
`;

const TopContainer = styled.View`
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const FirstModal = styled(Modal).attrs(() => ({
  animationType: 'slide',
  transparent: true,
}))``;

const ModalContent = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: pink;
`;

const BottomContainer = styled.View`
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const ButtonContainers = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
`;

const TitleContainer = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
`;
const TitleText = styled(Text).attrs(() => ({
  type: TextTypes.H2,
}))`
  color: ${({theme}) => theme.colors.primary};
`;
```

For what it is worth, I am trying to make something like this, but I do not want to keep adding multiple libraries and want to make it myself. https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet

Comment: Can you add a console.log to see if the item is being tapped, to see if the tap event is registering? Something like this `<Pressable onPress={() => {setModalVisible(true); console.log("Tapped");}}>
            <LeftTextRightIcon text="Sort" icon="chevron-down" />
          </Pressable>`

Comment: Yeah the console.log is not coming through.

Comment: You need to figure out why there is no onPress event, any clues what might be the reason?

Comment: No that is why I am asking. I'm sure exactly how Pressable works and why its not changing the state.

Comment: Instead of OnPress, can you try to add the console Pof to onPressIn and onPressOut events, to see if those get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. What was happening was the click was registering but nothing could be passed through. I fixed this by going to the LeftTextRightIcon text and making the surrounding div a TouchableOpacity instead of a View. This change allowed the function to be passed through. I am not sure if this is exactly how it works, but this is how I was able to make it work.

```
<Container {...props}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <CenterView>
          <ModalContent>
            <ModalTitle>
              <TitleText>{title}</TitleText>
            </ModalTitle>
            <ModalBody>
              <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <TitleText>Newest</TitleText>
                <CheckBox />
              </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
              <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <TitleText>Points High to Low</TitleText>
                <CheckBox />
              </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
              <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <TitleText>Brands A to Z</TitleText>
                <CheckBox />
              </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
            </ModalBody>
            <Pressable onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
              <TitleContainer>
                <TitleText>Close</TitleText>
              </TitleContainer>
            </Pressable>
          </ModalContent>
        </CenterView>
      </Modal>
      <TopContainer>
        <TitleContainer>
          <TitleText>{title}</TitleText>
        </TitleContainer>
        <ButtonContainers>
          <LeftTextRightIcon
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
            text="Sort"
            icon="chevron-down"
          />
          <LeftTextRightIcon text="Filter" icon="chevron-down" />
          <LeftTextRightIcon text="Category" icon="chevron-down" />
        </ButtonContainers>
      </TopContainer>
      <BottomContainer />
    </Container>
```

LeftTextRightIcon:

```
export interface ILeftTextRightIcon {
  icon: string;
  text: string;
  onPress?: any;
}

export const LeftTextRightIcon: React.FC<ILeftTextRightIcon> = ({
  icon = 'chevron-down',
  text,
  onPress,
  ...props
}) => (
  <LeftTextRightIconContainer onPress={onPress} {...props}>
    <DescriptionTextContainer>
      <DescriptionText> {text} </DescriptionText>
    </DescriptionTextContainer>
    <IconContainer>
      <Icon name={icon} type={vectorIconTypes.MEDIUM} />
    </IconContainer>
  </LeftTextRightIconContainer>
);

const LeftTextRightIconContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.colors.background};
  border-radius: 999px;
  padding -left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting in the answers instead of the comments because it's too long. Can you try this:

```
        ...
        {modalVisible &&
          (<FirstModal
            visible={modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
              setModalVisible(false);
            }}>
            <ModalContent>
              <TitleContainer>
                <TitleText>{title}</TitleText>
              </TitleContainer>
            </ModalContent>
          </FirstModal>)
        }
        ...
```

You can also try to play around with the styling, and see how if it works with no styling

Comment: Nothing happense here too. When I set the state to true in the useState hook it does show up, but the onPress is just not changing the state I guess. Also, I noticed that all the leftTextRightIcon components are pressable althought I have only wrapped the one for some reason.

Comment: @IbrahimNoorMohammed can you try to just say             onRequestClose={() => {
              setModalVisible(false);
            }}>

Comment: It's not the onRequestClose that is the problem, right? It's that the modal is not showing when I press the leftTextRightIcons text.

Comment: Ah its not displaying when you tap on: `<LeftTextRightIcon text="Sort" icon="chevron-down" />` ?